# How to perform nested apply in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to switch from pandas to pyspark and perform following operation:

For every employee (`employee` column), we have several records indicating the position (`position`) on which he was employed at given time (`date_key`). We want to calculate how many different positions had this employee looking three years back from each timestamp.

In pandas it sufficies to use:

```
df.apply(lambda tmp: tmp.apply(lambda x: tmp.loc[(tmp['date_key'] >= x['back']) & (tmp['date_key'] <= x['date_key']), 'position'].nunique(), axis=1)),
```

where `back` column stands for:

```
df['back'] = df['date_key'] - relative_delta(years=3)
```

Is there any way to implement this in spark?

This is how dataset looks now:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to calculate a cumulative count distinct of positions over window ranges between `date_key - 3 years` and `date_key`. You can use this :

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# example df
data = [
    ("1970-01-01 00:00:00.020200630", "50499555", "41888520"),
    ("1970-01-01 00:00:00.020203450", "50499555", "41888520"),
    ("1970-01-02 00:00:00.020200630", "50499555", "41888526"),
    ("1970-01-03 00:00:00.020200630", "50499555", "41888556"),
    ("1970-01-03 00:00:00.020200654", "50499555", "41888556")
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["date_key", "employee", "position"])

# one year has 365 * 86400 seconds
years = lambda i: i * 31536000

w = Window.partitionBy("employee") \
    .orderBy(F.to_timestamp("date_key").cast("long")).rangeBetween(-years(3), 0)

df1 = df.withColumn('distinct_positions', F.size(F.collect_set('position').over(w)))

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+-----------------------------+--------+--------+------------------+
#|date_key                     |employee|position|distinct_positions|
#+-----------------------------+--------+--------+------------------+
#|1970-01-01 00:00:00.020200630|50499555|41888520|1                 |
#|1970-01-01 00:00:00.020203450|50499555|41888520|1                 |
#|1970-01-02 00:00:00.020200630|50499555|41888526|2                 |
#|1970-01-03 00:00:00.020200630|50499555|41888556|3                 |
#|1970-01-03 00:00:00.020200654|50499555|41888556|3                 |
#+-----------------------------+--------+--------+------------------+
```